# Recommended location for APK to write to

Tags: android, apk

I want my APK to log some info to a text file that I can later access for debugging purpose.  What is the recommended location I should write to?  And do I need to do anything to my project configurations to grant my APK access to that location?

Some clarifications:

- Allowing this for debug builds only is fine.
- It is preferable if the data can be viewed from an adb shell outside
  Android Studio.
- The text file won't contain any sensitive data

Comment: "What is the recommended location I should write to?" -- I would use `getCacheDir()` or possibly `getExternalCacheDir()` on `Context`, personally. "And do I need to do anything to my project configurations to grant my APK access to that location?" -- no, which is why I would use them. 

Comment: The answer to your question depends on in which releases this log is activated (only your debug builds?), what it contains (any sensitive data in it?) and who should be able to access it (any user e.g. also via MTP on a connected PC or just you in case of debug builds e.g. via AndroidStudio).

Comment: @Robert I added some clarifications.

Comment: Then `getExternalCacheDir()` should point you to a working directory in `/sdcard/Android/data/com.exampleapp/cache/`